# Post-ban removal suggestions needed by reviewing of my questions

Tags: discussion, support, review, post-ban, revisions-list

I've been post-banned for about 4 months or more. I tried to give some answers. Also I tried to edit my questions but I can't make any big difference as I don't know the faults. Please kindly review my questions and if you think they are helpful, then you may give some up votes. Otherwise please give some suggestions on those to improve.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367858/nafis-abdullah-khan?tab=questions

Comment: Looking at your questions you must have some deleted questions as well? I think these will be the problem

Comment: Do you know why you were post banned?

Comment: @JoshC, no I don't.

Comment: Most likely deleted questions; ask a moderator to undelete couple that can be salvaged and keep posting answers.

Comment: @Richard, no I don't have deleted any questions, although I requested for deletion of the one most down voted question. But it already had answers so it was not deleted my the moderators.

Comment: You appear to no longer be blocked from asking.

Comment: Just a general tip: please don't start your titles with a tag.

Comment: @Bart, I thought "titles with a tag" is  the proper way to ask as I saw some questions like this before. From now on I won't do that.

Comment: It's most likely the two upvotes you received that put you on the good side of the equation again. But keep in mind that you'll still be fairly close to the ban. So make your next question a good one and keep contributing good content, so you won't fall back. Good luck.

Comment: Who is down voting this?! And why? It makes me sad when constructive requests for support are down voted

Comment: @RichardTingle: I agree. Maybe dvotes as similar questions exist? Though this issue is unique to the individual as to why *they* specifically were banned. Using the support tag to ask about your own issues and how to fix them should be supported with upvotes, to encourage it - only when search results don't answer your question of course.

Comment: @RichardTingle Perhaps because the OP is merely asking for upvotes? Granted, they obviously made good contributions, but can we encourage every banned user to come to MSO to ask people there to upvote their content? I'd rather they ask for specific issues with their posts and what to improve—the votes would come in more naturally that way.

Comment: @slhck perhaps, but I consider that a minor addition over "please review my posts". As we have a support tag dealing with user specific issues like that is on topic

Comment: @slhck 1+ Great point.

Comment: "no I don't have deleted any questions" - actually, you have (and had, at the time of asking) 3 deleted questions: 16991018, 17010990 and 17115375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've come up with the Post-ban situation very soon, I prefer answering my own question. From my experience and judgment I can suggest to everyone that, Mainly up votes to the questions may remove a Post-ban faster than up votes to answers. As I guess there also something exists called "Answer-ban" (I am not confirm) which may require up votes for answers. Answering questions may increase your reputation but most likely it won't help that much to rescue from your Post-ban. So, in short, Up-votes for Questions mostly helpful to remove Post-bans and up votes for answers mostly helpful to remove Answer-bans. So, edit the mistakes and hope for reviews and up votes.

The following list of approach from top to bottom could possibly be helpful:

1. Undelete the deleted questions which you've deleted by yourself.
2. Edit and fix the faults and make the questions more acceptable as much as possible.
3. Try giving good, helpful and correct answers to unsolved questions.
4. Try other possible approaches to improve your reputation from up votes like giving helpful comments.
5. Ask for reviews and suggestions to improve your questions in meta stackoverflow but only if you've already tried every other ways and waited for more than 1-2 months.

Comment: Up votes to answers _can_ remove a post ban under certain circumstances, unfortunately I can't really disclose what those circumstances are. Your reputation, overall, _is_ considered - this is how the algorithm manages to avoid new users that just got off on the wrong foot initially (well, most of the time).